Виртуальный телефон в Android Studio запущен, но не отображается на экране
При запуске виртуального телефона в Android Studio, он не отображается на экране, хотя Android Studio показывает, что устройство запущено. Виртуальный телефон также виден на панели задач и отображается в списке устройств при нажатии клавиш WIN + R. Однако, на экране его по-прежнему нет.
Это помогает только до закрытия. Если я закрою и снова попробую открыть виртуальный телефон, он снова не будет отображаться.

Дело может состоять в низкой производительности вашего компьютера. Как альтернативу, вы можете использовать отладку по COM или WI-FI.
